# How to map table names and column name different from model in onmodelcreating method in Entity Framework -6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have my database with table names starting with "tbl" prefix and column names like "ua_id" which are understandable in context of project but problematic if used in a model i.e names should be readable or meaningful(not like indicative names defined in database).

So I want to map them in my onmodelcreating method but I have no idea about it. I studied it in following blog:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/entity-framework-4-code-first-custom-database-schema-mapping
but this is for EF 4.1 and method doesn't work for EF 6.(mapsingletype method)

I  want to map my tables by columns to my model as I can't change the column names. I just want the newer version of that syntax in the blog.

Thank You.

Comment: Are you using code first?

Comment: Yes.I am using code first.

Comment: Added an answer for the Code First implementation.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you are using Code First, you can simply decorate your model with Table and Column attribute and give it the database names.

```
[Table("tbl_Student")]
public class Student
{
    [Column("u_id")]
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

These attributes are available in the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema namespace

Comment: So what is the limitation of data annotation as compared to fluent api and which is better.

Comment: I would prefer the annotation mechanism and there is no limitation between the two approaches. It is just neater to put it inside as an annotation that searching the OnModelCreating code for the name.

Comment: Ok. I'll try the data annotation first. Thank you for this blazing fast response.:-)

Comment: Both of the answers of Praveen and aSharma are worth marking as answer. I can mark only one but one should go with the example provided by Praveen+links provided by aSharma. Thanx to both of you.

Answer (score 7):

You can keep following inside OnModelCreating

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyModel>()
.Property(e => e.MyColumn).HasColumnName("DBColumn")
```

Comment: Thank you @aSharma. So If i have two tables,I need to write the above syntax two times? And where should I define the name of database table.

Comment: Yes, it is required to write this statement for each column. That's why it is preferable to use Configuration classes for the models. You can refer to http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165720/Using-the-Code-First-Model-Configuration-Classes and http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2011/11/28/composing-entity-framework-fluent-configurations.aspx if you are interested in Fluent Configurations style. It is a personal choice to use one of the styles. You'd need to weigh your options against your needs as Annotations provide only a subset of Fluent functionality.

Comment: FYR - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/476966/FluentplusAPIplusvsplusDataplusAnnotations-plusWor

Comment: Thank you for the links.I could not get this sentence:-"You'd need to weigh your options against your needs as Annotations provide only a subset of Fluent functionality" . Is fluent api better than data annotations? I meant what is that I can't do with data annotation as compared to fluent API.

Comment: I didn't say anything was better than the other, it is for you to decide according to your requirement. If you see the last link I posted, you'd understand what did I mean by 'subset'. You can search for the differences yourself as well. I have not used Annotations so can't talk much, but with Fluent it was easy to configure foreign key relations, cascade delete, RowVersion etc.

Comment: Ok.Currently I am going through your links. Thank you:-)

Answer (score 1):

And if you're not using code-first, just select a table in the model diagram, hit F4 (properties) and change the name.

Comment: I am using code first. I am using it for first time and I  found that generating a model is somewhat confusing to me. In code first I know what I am creating. Please tell me if I am wrong or any other idea is there.

Comment: In that case, go with @PraveenPaulose solution below.